# Does AutoMapper's convention based mappings work with LINQ extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, extension-methods, automapper

I apologize if this is a duplicate but I did not find anything that seemed to be matching up with what I am looking for.

As we all know in Automapper we can perform convention based mappings...

**My Question**

Is it possible to access extension methods (LINQ.First()) on objects in a collection, to go "n" levels deep?
See example below

**My Entities**

```
public class Store
{
    public IList< Departments > Departments {get;set;}
}

public class Departments
{
    public bool Open {get;set;}
}
```

**What I want to be able to do**

```
Mapper.Map< Store, StoreEditModel >();

public class StoreEditModel
{
    public bool DepartmentsFirstOpen {get;set;}
}
```

**Applicable Use (So you don't think I'm stupid)**

The applicable use is to assume that all items in the collection should be in the same (Open)state.

So when my edit model comes back to be processed, I can open or close all Departments in the Store respectively.

**Outside Resources**
I already read the following on AutoMapper's site....
http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening

Comment: I've open similar issue https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/34

Comment: Thanks Hazzik, it looks like jbogard doesn't want to support extension methods provided by linq by his comments to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like with the new release AutoMapper now supports this.

Source: http://automapper.org/blog/2011/09/22/automapper-20-released/